# Why have both _ViewStart and _ViewImports? Why not one file?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core MVC we can put a file with the exact name of `_ViewStart.cshtml` inside a folder to contain the common C# code to be run before every razor view/page in that folder. Something like this:

```
@{
    const string SomeConstant = "some value";
}
```

Similarly a file with the exact name of `_ViewImports.cshtml` inside a folder can hold all the common razor directives to be shared among the razor views/pages in that folder. Like this:

```
@layout _Layout
@using MyApp.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

But here's a question that I couldn't google, no matter how I rephrased it:

Can somebody please explain to me why we have both a `_ViewStart.cshtml` and a `_ViewImports.cshtml` to define common code & directives? Why aren't these functionalities (which don't seem to be conflicting with each-other) defined in a **single file**?

Comment: Because of a principle called *Separation of Concerns*. ViewImports cares about imports, ViewStart cares about logic required for the pages/views

Comment: But then the rest of the views care about directives AND logic AND markup...

Comment: Only if you want to. You can do everything, including the Layout, in a single file. What you do is only up to you

Comment: "Only if you want to"? I'm sorry, but your comments seem to contain more condescension than valid arguments... Please illuminate me: how can I uphold this "principle called Separation of Concerns" (that you apparently just educate me about) in my other .cshtml files? When was the last time you saw an actual razor page that didn't contain directives+markup+some c# all in one file? Isn't that the very reason "razor pages" were introduced to the MVC stack? </rant> And sorry for the anger-inducing backlash...

Comment: Razor Pages is another failed attempt for getting the interest of PHP users, or so Microsoft says, I wouldn't touch it. I have apps where the Views are only for loading the HTML and javascript, and others that just load Angular, and others that contain HTML and Razor.

Answer (score 14):

**The _ViewStart file**

It is used to set up shared-memory (public static variables) across all view files.

For example, the common practice for ViewStart is to set up a default value that you can override for the *Layout* and the *ViewData* / *ViewBag* dictionary.

**The _ViewImports file**

In this file you can summarize (abstract) all using statements that you commonly use in all your views.

**Why to use _ViewImports file for common "using directives" instead of ViewStart?**

Because using directives has the scope of the body of the current view file. So, putting @using statements inside ViewStart file won't make them available for any other view file except the body of the viewStart file itself. Therefore, comes the special ViewImports file which is designed to serve this scope extension purpose of the @using statements and other useful things, such as the tag helper, which without this special file, would be repeated inside each view file which violates the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) Principle](https://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/).

Comment: So you're saying `_ViewImports` is a workaround for a scoping issue in `_ViewStart`? We might want to put `@using` statements in `_ViewStart` (needed only for the logic in `_ViewStart`) without them being cascaded thru the whole folder? Well, thanks for the plausible answer, but to me that sounds like the exact opposite of DRY: Why would I want a `@using` statement in `_ViewStart` but NOT the rest of the files that share the logic? Why do I need to write the same `@using` statement again to now have access to it in the other files?

Comment: @HamidSadeghian, thanks for the comment which I agree with. However, currently the DRY principle is applied like this: The _ViewStart dries the body of the views while the _ViewImports dries the directives section of the views. The _ViewStart is the common body and the _ViewImports is the common header of directives. From my point of view, it's ok like this because sometimes I need to use some directives limited to the scope of the _ViewStart itself. May be this will change in the future.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that has been overlooked in the other answers is that according to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

- Code in the *_ViewStart.cshtml* file will **only** be run for non-layout pages.
- Code in the *_ViewImports.cshtml* file will be run for both layout and non-layout pages.

I've tested this by moving the default Application Insights JavaScript snippet (the code below) from the imports file to the start file and it causing a build error on my layout page as it can no longer find the defined variable `JavaScriptSnippet`.

The code I moved:

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
```

Given this, the difference between the files is probably 'code I want to run everywhere' vs 'code I want to only run for full views', similar to the difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Code that needs to be executed before each page should be placed _ViewStart.cshtml file.

For _ViewImport.cshtml - the contents of this file applied to all the files present in the same folder and subfolder.

So _ViewStart is execution whereas _ViewImport applies its content to each file.

**TEST1**
Placing both "Layout [**Correct**]" reference and "using statement[Incorrect]" at **_ViewStart** will give compiler Error.

**TEST2**
Placing both "Layout [InCorrect]" reference and "using statement[**Correct**]" at **_ViewImport** will not apply _Layout to other pages

As per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ViewImport Support following directives

@addTagHelper, @removeTagHelper: all run, in order.

@tagHelperPrefix: the closest one to the view overrides any others

@model: the closest one to the view overrides any others

@inherits: the closest one to the view overrides any others

@using: all are included; duplicates are ignored

@inject: for each property, the closest one to the view overrides any others with the same property name